# Unable to verify force.com ownership for Google app verification despite trying various methods

Tags: google-apps, google-drive

I have been trying to verify ownership of force.com domain of Salesforce for Google app verification using different methods, including uploading an HTML file, adding a meta tag, using Google Analytics, Google Tag Manager, and associating a DNS record with Google. However, none of these methods have worked for me.

Please refer
Related Issue for community site - **[community site issue](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000393278&type=1)**

The above issue is for salesforce community site but my problem is in  salesforce Org.

example my org domain - **https://Test-org-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/**

while authorizing to google it containing **force.com**.

**my salesforce Org domain contains force.com** so i need to verify the ownership of it by following any one of this method below

**Google app verification using different methods.**

1). including uploading an HTML file, adding a meta tag.

2). using Google Analytics.

3). associating a DNS record with Google.

4). Google Tag Manager.

[image: Google Auth]

I have followed the instructions provided by Google's [documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080#html_verification&zippy=%2Chtml-file-upload) for each method, but I keep getting an error message saying that the ownership cannot be verified.

Can someone please provide me with some additional guidance on how to proceed with the verification process or suggest another method that I could try? I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain exactly what you are trying to do, why and provide reference to the documentation you have followed. As it stands, I do not understand what you are doing. Are you trying to claim ownership of a Salesforce generated domain?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.